# How to include iOS SDK lower than 4.3 in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, sdk

I just upgrade my Xcode to 4.2 because I upgraded my MacOS to Lion.

In this version of Xcode. only includes SDK 4.3, I can set the Deploy Target to 4.0 or other lower version, but different from old Xcode, I can't launched Simulators for lower SDKs.

I also tried download & install lower SDKs from old Xcode package, but seems it doesn't works.

So, in this situation, how I can publish app to support lower SDK devices?

THX~

Comment: Try waiting until Xcode 4.2 is released. You might also  be able to install Xcode 4.0.2 on Lion; I dunno. In the past, the App Store has not accepted apps built with beta versions of the SDK (discounting the "GM").

Answer (score 3):

Try opening XCode preferences, go to Downloads, and install the various debugging support options that are present.

Comment: That's clear, thank you. But what if it says "<my_apple_id> is not registered as an apple developer" and cancels instal. How do I change that ID to the proper one?